# why isn't it being displayed properly?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm currently developing an online store where people can add products to carts. In my home html file I want to display the button 'Add to cart' if the product is not added to cart, and 'Remove from cart' if the product is added. But it is not working properly. I'm getting 'Remove from cart' button now.
My index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block content %}
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <div class="container-md">
        <div class="row">
            {% for product in products %}
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card-deck" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="{{ product.image_url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <a class="card-title" href="{% url 'detail-view' product.slug %}">{{ product.name }}</a>
                        <p class="card-text">${{ product.price }}</p>
                        {% if product in Cart.products.all %}
                            <a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' product.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
                        {% else %}
                            <a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' product.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Remove from Cart</a> 
                        {% endif %}

                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

My cart's views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponseRedirect
from products.models import Product
from .models import Cart
from django.contrib import messages
from django.urls import reverse


def cart(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.all()[0]
    context = {"cart":cart}
    template = 'shopping_cart/cart.html'
    return render(request, template, context)


def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    cart = Cart.objects.all()[0]
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass 
    if not product in cart.products.all():
        cart.products.add(product)
        messages.success(request, f'Product added to cart')
        return redirect('myshop-home')
    else:
        cart.products.remove(product)
        messages.success(request, f'Product removed from cart')
        return redirect('myshop-home')

    new_total = 0.00
    for item in cart.products.all():
        new_total += float(item.price)

    cart.total = new_total
    cart.save()


    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart'))
```

my Cart's models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from products.models import Product


class Cart(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, null=True, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Cart"
```

Comment: can you share your models please?

Comment: I added my cart's models.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
{% if product in Cart.products.all %}
      <a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' product.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
{% else %}
     <a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' product.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Remove from Cart</a> 
{% endif %}
```

You can try like this:

```
{% if not product.cart_set.exists %}
     <a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' product.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
{% else %}
     <a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' product.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Remove from Cart</a> 
{% endif %}
```

I am using [**`reverse relation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/) to check if there is any cart exists for that product. But it checks if this product is in any cart. Which should not be correct, because it should check if the product is in a specific cart.

Now, if you want to be more specific by if this product exists in certain cart, I would recommend doing this calculation in views. For example, in your product view you can do it like this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, BooleanField

cart = Cart.objects.first()

products = Product.objects.annotate(in_cart=Case(When(cart__pk=cart.id,then=Value(True)),default=Value(False),output_field=BooleanField()))

return render(request, template.html, context={'products':products})
```

And check in template:

```
{% if not product.in_cart %}
          <a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' product.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
{% else %}
         <a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' product.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Remove from Cart</a> 
{% endif %}
```

I am using django's [**`conditional expression`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) here to check if product is in certain cart.

### Maybe something more simple bug occurred in your code:

Add a **not** in your `if` `else` logic:

```
{% if not product in Cart.products.all %}
      <a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' product.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
{% else %}
     <a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' product.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Remove from Cart</a> 
{% endif %}
```